# Microsoft Excel 2010: =NETWORKDAYS()

Tags: excel, ms-office

I am having a problem with the =NETWORKDAYS() function.

Here is my table:

```
        A            B            C
    Start date    End Date      #Days
1   15/05/2012    17/05/2012
```

In `C1` I have entered the formula `=NETWORKDAYS(A1,B1)`

The answer should be `2`, but I'm getting `01/01/1900`.

For each date in the table, I have used the date function, eg: `=DATE(2012,05,15)`

Any help will be appreciated.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You formula `=NETWORKDAYS(A1,B1)` should give the result  `3`.

And you are getting result as `01/01/1900` which is saying value is `1` but `cell format` is set to `Date`. That's why it is displaying in date format.  Change cell number format to General.

Answer (score 0):

To fix this right-click on your cell and choose Format Cells or navigate to Format -> Cells.  From the window that appears click Number and choose 0 as the number of decimals.